# Counter variable issue with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React app, I got a state variable that's set to `0` at first.

```
const [amount, setAmount] = useState(0)
```

The functionality i'm looking for is to add/remover product in a redux store.

So if a user presses a `"+"` button, it will check if `amount` is now bigger than `0`,
and if so it'll `dispatch` an action to the store.
But what I'm getting is that only after the second `"+"` press, when the value of `amount` is already `2`,
the action is actually dispatched.
This is the code :

```
const handleAmount = action => {
    if (action === 'plus') {
      setAmount(currAmount => currAmount + 1)
      updateStore()
    }
  }

const updateStore = () => {
    if (amount >= 1) {
      dispatch(addToCart(product))
    }
  }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide us with the code of your action and reducer?

Comment: Why don't you implement `amount` in redux also? `setState` applies changes only in the next render. Redux and useReducer on the other hand give you the current state once they have changed.

Answer (score 3):

State is updated asynchronously, so when you call `updateStore` right after calling `setAmount`, state hasn't updated yet, so `updateStore` function sees the old value of `amount`.

When you click the second time, it works because now the updated value of `amount` will be 2 and the old value that `updateStore` function will use is 1, so the condition `if (amount >= 1)` evaluates to true and as a result the action is dispatched.

You can fix this problem using one of the following options:

- Pass the new value of `amount` to `updateStore` function as an argument
- Use the `useEffect` hook that executes whenever `amount` changes. Just move the code inside `updateStore` function inside `useEffect` hook and add `amount` in the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook.

  ```
  useEffect(() => {
     if (amount >= 1) {
        dispatch(addToCart(product))
     }
  }, [amount]);
  ```

  and remove the `updateStore` function, you don't need it if you use the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: What logic should I put inside `useEffect`?